# Stellen as a question to ask?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

> Das sind Fragen, die euch ein Verkäufer in einem Supermarkt oder auf einem Markt stellen könnte.

My question is, in this context does "stellen" represent the act of asking?

Comment: Yes. To ask a question: Eine Frage stellen.

Comment: Yes, but "stellen" alone wouldn't cut it. The noun "Frage" is required in combination with stellen. "Ich stelle eine Frage." -> "I am asking a question." In contrast to English, we can also say: "Ich frage." -> "I am asking [a question]." In the latter case, the "question" is implied.

Comment: Greetings and thanks are, by convention, unwanted here. Your thanks shall be executed by voting up good answers.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, *to ask a question* is *eine Frage stellen*.

English also has *to pose a question* and, for some uses, *to put a question*. It's just much more common in German.

One reason is probably the fact that "eine Frage fragen" would sound silly.

Comment: Silly, yes. But not wrong. :)

Comment: @henning Darf ich mal eine Frage fragen? - Klar, aber ob sie auch antwortet?

Answer (score 7):

The correct sentence in German would be:

> Das sind Fragen, die euch ein Verk**ä**ufer in eine**m** Supermarkt oder auf eine**m M**arkt stellen könnte.

"Stellen" has lots and lots of meanings, similar to "put" in English. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stellen) lists 16, of which the last applies to the sentence in question, and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/stellen) lists 14, while not directly mentioning this case.

It's a special case of forming the meaning of the verb together with a noun. In this case, "stellen" has to be combined with a noun ("Frage(n)") to make sense. Different nouns + "stellen" can have different translations. Taken from the Duden examples:

- (jmd.) eine Aufgabe stellen = to give/set (sb.) a task
- eine Bedingung stellen = to impose a condition
- eine Bitte stellen = to make a request
- eine Frage stellen = to ask a question
- einen Antrag stellen = to file an application

etc.

Comment: The grammatical term for this is "light verb". English has a number of them too such as "make" ("make amends"), "take" ('take charge"), "do" ("do dishes"). Other light verbs in German are *machen*, *treffen*, *nehmen*, *bringen*, *treten*; see the respective Wiktionary entries for example meanings.

Comment: @rdbury The proper German grammar term for "light verbs" is "Funktionsverben"

Comment: @RDBury Thanks! TIL...